# How to change velocityx of sidemenu in onsen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

So I feel like it is not easy to swipe a menu in and out when compared to other apps. I find the easiest way is to modify onsenui.js increase the Hammer.gestures.Swipe event velocity from swipeVelocityX:0.6 to 0.2

I'm new to angular and onsen (and also JS) so forgive me if its a stupid question but how do I change this within my app.js or custom code instead of in onsenui.js? I don't want to have to keep doing these+future changes everytime there is new version of onsen.

Comment: Try changing `Hammer.gestures.Swipe.defaults.swipeVelocityX` right after loading `onsenui.js`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasArgelius, changed it jsut before calling onsen through angular... Easier than I thought and worked like a charm!